# Use solr,How can i enter "AB" can match "ABCD"

Tags: solr

In solr schema.xml

I have a field

```
    <field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

this value can be

- abcd108-102
- abcd107-102
- axcd807-102

and so on

how can i enter the *"ab"*,match to the "abcd108-102","abcd107-102"?

enter the *"bc"*, match to the "abcd108-102","abcd107-102"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways that I can think of:

1. Tokenize your text on nGrams where n=length on which you want to search on, so in your case it would be 2.
2. Take a look at [TermsComponent](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/TermsComponent)